# How to run SharePoint 2019 on-premise under docker

Tags: docker, sharepoint, docker-compose, sharepoint-2013, hyper-v

I'm a new to the SharePoint world, I've found that to make a SharePoint development environment,
I need to install windows server 2019 on HyperV VM, to install later the SharePoint and SQL server.

Therefore, I found myself need to install also the Visual Studio in this environment, for publishing the solution on the SharePoint.

My question here is:

**Could I replace the HyperV VM with all those programs with a Docker Image?**

If not, Is there is any way to work on the solution in my visual studio and link it's publishing to publish in the VM instead of installing visual studio inside the VM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you planning on developing? Web parts using SPFX?

Comment: No, there is no plan to to develop using SPFX, only using SharePoint on-premise.

Comment: I guess that you should start tryingto create a docker with Windows Server + AD and SQLServer, or a docker compose with those 2 instances. Then move forward